# Cannot create "Spring Starter Project" with STS 3.9.4

Tags: proxy, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to create a Spring Starter Project with STS 3.9.4. I see the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following approaches:

- I looked at proxy settings in STS and set the "Active Provider" to manual. The help -> dashboard successfully rendered implying that it was able to tunnel through the proxy but the spring-starter-project was still failing.
- I cleared the local password storage but still ran into the same issue.
- I tried various settings of the "Active Provider" and the errors for the Spring Starter Project varied implying that it was definitely using the proxy settings in STS but was failing for some reason.

After some digging I found this in Java SE release notes:
[**Disable Basic authentication for HTTPS tunneling**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html)

I realized immediately that I had upgraded the version of JDK a few days ago. I believe I had Java SE 8 u45 prior to the upgrade. I had upgraded it to Java SE 8 u111 and the above change was causing the issue.

I added the following line in STS.ini and it solved the problem.
`-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""`